# Google Maps MarkerWithLabel and custom Icon not working correctly

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I have a basic google map on which I'm trying to add markers using the MarkerWithLabel extension. I have to load the coordinates from a json object, and on the label I have to put the sort order of the markers, which is also from the json.

The problem is that the custom icon I load for the markers only works on the last one and I can't figure out why. They all position correctly, but the other ones do not have an icon.

Here is the function I used to add the markers :

```
function CreateTourMarkers(json) {
    if (json.length > 0) {
        json.forEach(function (item) {
            var myCoord = new google.maps.LatLng(item.Lat, item.Lng);
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: myCoord,
                map: vehiclesMap,
                icon: {
                    url: image
                },
                labelContent: item.SortOrder,
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(5, 37),
                labelClass: "map-labels",
                marker: MarkerWithLabel,
                labelInBackground: false
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Also here is a fiddle showing the problem : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwr8u/2/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's so strange!! Your code seems ok. I think the problem is in JS file. Is there another version??

Comment: oh, it looks like I didn't do my searches very well before posting. But I was just stuck with the idea that my code is wrong and not that this is a bug from the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your Fiddle to use the v1.1.9 of markerwithlabel.js and it shows the custom icon on all markers so I'm assuming it must be a bug with v1.1.8.

Comment: Yup, you're right. This was getting really frustrating here. Thanks for the help. I will accept this as the correct answer, but I'm kind of curious now as to what the bug was in the old version :)

Comment: @Bobby5193 It's also about the new version of Google Maps API. Seems MarkerWithLabel v1.1.8 is incompatible with Google Maps API v3.15. If you add `v=3.14` parameter to API call and use v1.1.8 of plugin, you will probably see no problem.